# Editor push content to Contentful

Tags: contentful, contentful-management, contentful-api

I am making my own editor in Vue.js. I can change text and add images etc. I want that content to be pushed to Contentful when I save the changes I made in my editor app. I have checked out the Content Management API and this seems feasible but I don't really know how to start. The extentions for Contentful only focus on creating new stuff for the Contentful webapp and not on creating an editor. Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Contentful's value proposition is to be your content editor in the cloud. It offers you an editor-friendly interface that you don't have to maintain. Non-technical people can create/edit/update content. Usually, there shouldn't be a need to build your own editor interface on top of Contentful.

If you want to use Contentful as a "storage-layer" the [CMA](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/) is the way to go. That said, theoretically, you could put any interface on top of the CMA API. The question is, though, if you should?

Why you want to use Contentful in the first place because you'd be throwing away one of its core-features (the editor). If you're not planning on using the Contentful editor you could also go with a cloud database instead. :)

> The extensions for Contentful only focus on creating new stuff for the Contentful webapp and not on creating an editor

This is correct. **Contentful UI-extensions are there to enrich the existing experience**. Their use cases range from custom selects to fancy third-party integrations.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Yeah this is great, we want to use the Contentful editor within the company, the editor customers use will be our platform (which does allot more things than just content editing). I did look at cloud database/storage but Contentful already offers a nice API and the editor give us the opportunity to edit the content in that 'database' directly.